# Xcode Label resizes View

Tags: macos, autolayout

Imagine a **NSView** which contains a **NSLabel** and constraints to **leading >= 10** and **trailing >= 10**. Now when I change the **StringContent**, the **NSLabel** autoresizes (like it should) but it also resizes the whole **NSView**.

Here is a screenshot of Xcode

[image]

The window on startup:

[image]

And the window after the Stringvalue has changed:

[image]

Note that I cannot shrink the window to a smaller size than the labels

Is there a way to stop the NSLabel resizing the NSView without setting a maxwidth?
So maybe the StringValue would be "This is an extreme long text I want to dis..." and when resizing the NSView, the Label resizes with it and will show the whole StringValue

Thanks in advance for your help!

## Solution

The key was setting the **Content Compression Resistance Priority** to a lower than standard, in my case I set it to 500

Comment: Constrain the maximum width of the label?

Comment: How are the constraints set on your NSView? The label should only change the view's size if the view's size is determined by the label's size.

Comment: @BallpointBen But I want the label to resize with the view

Comment: @MatthewCawley The NSView is the RootView inside a ViewController, so it hasn't any constraints I think

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin NSView size should be determined based on what ?

Comment: @DannieP The NSView is inside a Stackview and will be resized to fit the width

Comment: And what's determining the size of the stack view?  Something has to determine what the actual sizes of these views are.  NSView and stack view are just containers that have no intrinsic size of their own so since the label is the only thing that has an intrinsic size, its size gets propagated up the whole hierarchy.

Comment: @dan Okay I see, I updated the post the show the hierarchy. Tell me if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try selecting your label and setting it's horizontal content hugging priority to something less. Here's how it looks:

[image: xcode]

Comment: Unfortunately it still resizes the Window, also if I set the hugging to 1

Comment: can you share your sample project?

Comment: Your answer leaded me to the solution, so I'll accept your post ;)